# Parse Server Express Routes and Auth

Tags: node.js, express, parse-platform, parse-server

I'm using Parse Server and I have an external client that will make calls to my Parse API using a rest client.  This client will be using the Parse JS lib and will be authenticated.

I can't expose the Parse Rest API cause I have a lot of business rules to check in other MongoDB database before return the response.

Can I create custom Express routes that are authenticated by Parse without cloud functions?

[Parse Cloud Express](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-cloud-express) helps but as I have a lot of business rules I'm looking to keep it as Express routes.